# Get remaining days between now to DateMidnight class

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a due date as `DateMidnight` type - `DateMidnight return_due_date`  and I want to compute the days left from now until this  date .

How can I compute that ?

[DateMidnight documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int days = org.joda.time.Days.daysBetween(DateMidnight.now(), yourDueDate).getDays();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [org.joda.time.Days](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html) class.  It provides some `daysBetween` methods to compute exactly what you need.

```
DateMidnight midnight = return_due_date; // your DateMidnight instance
DateTime now = new DateTime();

int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(now, midnight).getDays();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done:

```
import org.joda.time.DateMidnight;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;


public class example {

/**
 * How many days until a certain date.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DateMidnight someDate = new DateMidnight(2013,6,26);
    System.out.println("An example due date: "+someDate);
    DateTime timeNow = new DateTime();
    System.out.println("The time right now: "+timeNow);
    int daysToDeadLine = Days.daysBetween(timeNow, someDate).getDays();
    System.out.println("Days until deadline: "+daysToDeadLine);

}}
```

May I also suggest a little more effort on your behalf next time? :)

Comment: -1: Scolding someone for not googling an answer goes against the spirit of StackOverflow.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5283/148212

Comment: Scolding? I think this is a constructive side note, after I took the time to download this JAR and write a working example of what this fellow tried to do. I think it's also quite friendly and positive - after all, StackOverflow also states you should show at least some research effort in your question.

Answer (score 0):

here comes simple & nice library for such purposes
https://code.google.com/p/stringtotime/